# Get list of checked out files in TFS error

Tags: powershell, tfs

I'm trying to get a list of checked out / pending files in TFS through tf.exe command line.

- All the users connected are using Local Workspace
- Manual check out with Lock type: Check In - Allow other users to check out but prevent them from checking in
- TFS 2013 and VS 2013

When I run the powershell script

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" status /user:*

I do get the list of pending checked out files but it also gives me the error message as follow:
*tf.exe : Changes from local workspaces will not be displayed when using the /user option if a workspace is not supplied or if that workspace is on another machine...*

Is there anyway to just get the list and not throw the error? I'm trying to use this script in a build server to check if any files have been manually checked out.

I know by switching to Server workspace this issue would not be present which is not an option at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could redirect the stderr output to a log file e.g.:

```
tf status . /r /user:* 2>tf-status-err.log
```

You can also use the TeamFoundation PowerShell snapin that comes with the Team Foundation Server Power Tools.

```
Import-Module Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell
Get-TfsPendingChange . -Recurse -User * | Select -Exp PendingChanges | Format-List *
```

The PowerShell command is nice because you don't have to parse text like you would with the output of tf status.

Comment: The first option gets results that I can't use in my script. I tried the second option but nothing gets printed out, which I'm assuming it means that nothing is "pending change"

Comment: If there are no pending changes by your users then yeah the output would be empty.  But are you saying tf status displays pending changes while Get-TfsPendingChange doesn't for the same directory?

Comment: Yes. tf status shows a list while get-tfspendingchange doesn't. Unless my syntax is incorrect. I'm pretty much copying and pasting what you have using windows powershell ise.

Comment: It should show the same pending changes.  Do you see anything if you run just `Get-TfsPendingChange . -Recurse -User *`?

Comment: No luck. Since I'm running this code in Windows PowerShell ISE, the code i run to get the list of pending user list is `& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe" status /user:*` and the syntax I use to run your code is `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell` since the import doesn't work.

Comment: For ISE, make sure you are using the x86 version of ISE and instead of Import-Module, use `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.TeamFoundation.PowerShell`.  Then try the Get-TfsPendingChange command shown in the answer.